# How to change the TEMP directory on Windows Jenkins

Tags: windows, jenkins

I have a very simple build on Windows Jenkins that should execute a shell command.

However, the C:\Windows\Temp directory is not writable by Jenkins on my machine, and so the shell script is never written and never executed (apparently). I would like to change it to D:\TEMP.

Can anyone explain how to go about doing that for Windows?

Answer (score 2):

As with most cases, I discovered the problem almost immediately upon writing the question.

I should be executing a Windows Batch Command instead of a Shell. This solved my problem.